# Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found while building angular asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, angular

[image]I am trying to deploy the ASP.NET Core 2.0 + Angular 2/4 - User Registration and Login application on IIS server taken from the link https://www.pointblankdevelopment.com.au/blog/134/aspnet-core-20-angular-24-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example

I am able to successfully import the project in Visual Studio Community 2017 and run the application through terminal using "npm i" and "npm start"

But when Iam trying to build the project using the command "ng build --prod --base-href /loginreg/", I am getting the error as shown below in the image below.....

```
Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
    at WorkspaceLoader._getProjectWorkspaceFilePath (/home/travis/build/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/workspace-loader.js:37:19)
    at WorkspaceLoader.loadWorkspace (/home/travis/build/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/workspace-loader.js:24:21)
    at TestCommand._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect (/home/travis/build/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:177:32)
    at TestCommand.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:45:25)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/travis/build/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/travis/build/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:3:12)
    at TestCommand.initialize (/home/travis/build/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:44:16)
    at /home/travis/build/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:100:23
```

Then again i deleted nodemodules folder and package-lock.json file from the project and run the cmd "npm install" , "npm start" and then "ng build --prod --base-href /loginreg/", but its not working.

I also tried to run the following command "ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4" by referring the various solutions..But again iam facing the same issue.

Later i also tried "ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false" command ,i am unable to resolve it..

Can anybody please solve my issue...?

### And this is my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "aspnet-core-angular2-registration-login-example-client",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Client for ASP.NET Core with Angular 2/4 User Registration and Login Example",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/cornflourblue/aspnet-core-angular2-registration-login-example.git"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^4.4.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.5",
        "@angular/core": "^4.4.5",
        "@angular/forms": "^4.4.5",
        "@angular/http": "^4.4.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.5",
        "@angular/router": "^4.4.5",
        "core-js": "^2.5.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
        "systemjs": "^0.20.19",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^6.0.0-rc.4",
        "@types/node": "^8.0.34",
        "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
        "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
        "typescript": "^2.5.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: If the compiler is looking for "angular.json" that means it takes your project to be Angular6 project. But before angular6, angular.json is replaced by .angularcli file which has all the information. You have updated your angular/cli package to 6.0.0, downgrade it to 1.7.4 (please verify the version). Doing this, it will start working.

Comment: I tried to downgrade the angular/cli by running the following commands. npm uninstall -D @angular/cli
npm install -D @angular/cli@5.2.0

Comment: but I am facing a different issue now .. please check the edited question i have pasted my error screenshot......!

Comment: @inthevortex.... please help me to solve this issue............!

Comment: The command should be "npm install @angular/cli@1.7.4"

Comment: @inthevortex... should i first uninstall using the command.... npm uninstall -D @angular/cli........ then install ..?

Comment: Yes first uninstall and then install.